# Writing a wrapper with my own exceptions

Tags: c++, oop, exception

I want to make a FileIO class which will provide some methods like write or read. Also I want to hide the implementation of FileIO (currently, it just derives from std::fstream). The problem is that std::fstream could throw some exceptions but I don't want my FileIO class to throw std::fstream exceptions, I want to throw my own (e.g. FileIO::SomethingBadHappened). Is there an elegant way to do this?

**My solution** is to just rewrite every method of std::fstream with an additional try/catch block.

**EDIT:** FileIO class is just an example. I'm looking for a general solution for wrapping an arbitrary class.

Comment: Your "solution" is obviously wrong. And so is the problem. What is wrong with using `fstream` directly? It's there to be used, not to be wrapped.

Comment: I would strongly advise against using inheritance here.  If you're trying to mediate access to the file stream, just write a wrapper class around it so that you don't need to worry about these exceptions (you can just avoid calling `exceptions`).  Using inheritance is problematic here.

Comment: The problem is that FileIO could change and could use WinApi to file i/o instead of std::fstream.

In this current example I can avoid calling exceptions, but what if I use something else than std::fstream?

Comment: @Kele: Which is what `fstream` already does... are you under the impression that it does not use the Windows API under... Windows?  `fstream` solved this problem already, what problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: @EdS. That's just an example, I'm looking for a general solution.

Comment: @Kele: A general solution *to what problem*?  You said - *"The problem is that FileIO could change and could use WinApi to file i/o instead of std::fstream"*, but of course `fstream` already does that for you, i.e., it solves the cross-platform problem by using the correct OS API's, so I'm confused.

Comment: @Kele: Better yet, [let Raymond Chen explain what I am getting at](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx)

Comment: @EdS. FileIO is an example, it could be any class.

Comment: So this is a rhetorical question?  Then you'll have to wrap every function call in a try/catch and pray that you don't screw it up.

Comment: @EdS. That's why I asked whether there is an elegant way other than wrapping every function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way around it - you have to put a try/catch block around any function call that can generate an exception if you want to rethrow a different exception.

Rather than using inheritance, you should use encapsulation - have your class own an object that you can propagate your calls to. This allows you to simplify your interface, only providing the capabilities needed and thus not needing to wrap *every single method* of the underlying class that does the work.

Answer (score 3):

The "elegant" way to do this is to not reinvent the wheel.  Especially this wheel, which has traveled to and from the Moon thousands of times.  It's tried and true.  You don't need to invent this *there*.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean with 'this wheel'.